# ¿Como ingresar valores y frases de una estructura a un archivo txt en c?

Tags: c

Al momento de querer guardar los valores solo me captura el primer nombre y valor y los demás no los guarda ni los muestra, ademas, si quiero intentar usar `fgets` no me deja poner el nombre.

Código:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#define personas 3

struct datos{

    char nombre[30];
    int clave;
}alumnos[];

int main()
{
    FILE *archivo;
    struct datos alumnos[personas];
    int indice,agregar;
    do
    {
        archivo=fopen("lista.txt","wb");
        printf("Ingresa el nombre del alumno #%d",(indice+1));
        scanf("%s",&alumnos[indice].nombre);
        fflush(stdin);
        printf("Ingresa la clave #%d",(indice+1));
        scanf("%d",&alumnos[indice].clave);
        fflush(stdin);
        fprintf(archivo,"\n %s\n %i",alumnos[indice].nombre,alumnos[indice].clave);
        indice++;

        scanf("%d",&agregar);

    }while(agregar==1);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Observaciones:

**1.-** Estás definiendo un array de estructuras con ámbito global y luego vuelves a definir otro array con el mismo nombre pero con ámbito local.

Es decir, este código:

```c
struct datos{

    char nombre[30];
    int clave;
}alumnos[];
```

Es como si hicieras esto:

```c
struct datos{

    char nombre[30];
    int clave;
};
struct datos alumnos[];
```

No necesitas definir este array de estructuras porque ya lo haces en la función `main`. Además, en C no puedes omitir el tamaño del **array** (de ley debes especificarle una longitud).

**2.-** La variable `indice` **nunca** es inicializada, por lo tanto, tiene **contenido basura**. En este caso, es valor por defecto de esta variable debería ser `0`, ya que para recorrer el *array* se empieza desde la posición `0`.

**3.-** No necesitas invocar a la función `fopen` en cada iteración, no hace falta. Esto solo ocasiona que ocurra [fuga de memoria](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fuga_de_memoria), porque perdemos la referencia del bloque anterior.

**4.-** Falta invocar la función `fclose`. Es buena práctica cerrar los recursos cuando ya no lo necesites.

**5.-** La variable `agregar` es innecesaria. Porque el programa solo pedirá información al usuario hasta cierto límite (en este caso `3`), así que no puedes usar esta condición como salida del bucle:

```c
agregar==1
```

De lo contrario, si se llegara a pedir más información del límite establecido, ocurriría un [desbordamiento de búfer](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Desbordamiento_de_b%C3%BAfer).

La condición de salida debería ser así:

```c
indice < personas
```

Con las observaciones mencionadas anteriormente, el código quedaría así:

```c
struct datos{

    char nombre[30];
    int clave;
};

int main()
{
    FILE *archivo =fopen("lista.txt","wb");
    struct datos alumnos[personas];
    int indice = 0;
    do
    {
        printf("Ingresa el nombre del alumno #%d",(indice+1));
        scanf("%s", alumnos[indice].nombre);
        fflush(stdin);
        printf("Ingresa la clave #%d",(indice+1));
        scanf("%d",&alumnos[indice].clave);
        fflush(stdin);
        fprintf(archivo,"\n %s\n %i",alumnos[indice].nombre, alumnos[indice].clave);
        indice++;
    }while(indice < personas); 
    fclose(archivo);
    return 0;
}
```

El código de arriba escribirá en el archivo después de pedir los tres datos al usuario.

La función [fflush](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fflush/) no limpia el búfer **stdin**, sino el **stdout**. Por más que funcione en algunos sistemas, no se recomienda su uso por cuestión de portabilidad.

Una manera de hacerlo de forma estándar (que funcione en cualquier plataforma) es de esta manera:

```c
while(getchar() != '\n');
```

El código completo (junto con [fgets](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fgets/)) quedaría así:

```c
int main()
{
    FILE *archivo =fopen("lista.txt","wb");
    struct datos alumnos[personas];
    int indice = 0;
    do
    {
        printf("Ingresa el nombre del alumno #%d",(indice+1));
        fgets(alumnos[indice].nombre, 30, stdin);
        printf("Ingresa la clave #%d",(indice+1));
        scanf("%d",&alumnos[indice].clave);
        //Limpiamos el búfer del teclado
        while(getchar() != '\n');
        fprintf(archivo,"\n %s\n %i",alumnos[indice].nombre, alumnos[indice].clave);
        indice++;
    }while(indice < personas); 
    fclose(archivo);
    return 0;
}
```

**Nota:** Se debe tomar en cuenta que la función `fgets` incluirá el salto de línea en el *array* `nombre` si no lee la cantidad máxima de caracteres que le especificamos en el segundo parámetro (en este caso es `30`).

Comment: hola, me funciono perfecto pero al momento de ponerlo adentro de un switch me salta para poner el primer nombre al igual que si lo pongo en un arrreglo, eso a que se debe?

Comment: @JoseCast Se te salta el nombre, es decir, ¿no te deja ingresar el nombre?

Comment: si, no me deja ingresar el nombre , solo aparece:" ingresar nombre #1 ingresar clave #1 :"

Comment: @JoseCast Antes de pedir el nombre, invocas a la función scanf?

Comment: ya con la clave 1 no hay problema en adelante

Comment: no, con fgets y la clave con scanf

Comment: ya me funciono , puse un ` while(getchar() != '\n');` antes del ingresar el nombre y ya me dejo ingresarlo , gracias

Comment: @JoseCast Justamente eso te iba a decir. De seguro usaste antes del switch la función scanf para pedir que opción del menú quiere elegir el usuario, con esto, el búfer del teclado queda sucio, entonces, al entrar a la opción donde pides el nombre, la función `fgets` no pausará el programa porque el búfer stdin quedó sucio. Me da gusto que te haya servido. Saludos!

Comment: gracias por la ayuda